# Select duplicate values in one column in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have this table:

```
id int, name nvarchar(max), ..............
```

Example:

```
 ------------------
| id  | name       |
 ------------------
| 1   | Mohammed   | 
| 2   | Mohammed   |    
| 3   | Sakher     |
| 4   | Sakher     |
| 5   | Ahmad      |
| 6   | Ahmad      |
| 11  | Hasan      |
| 50  | Hasan      |
| 17  | Sameer     |
| 19  | Soso       |
| 110 | Omar       |
| 113 | Omar       |
| 220 | Omar       |
 ------------------
```

I am trying to write a query to result this:

```
id1 int , id2 int , name nvarchar(max)
```

Example:

```
 ------------------------
| id1 | id2 | name       |
 ------------------------
|  1  |  2  | Mohammed   |
|  3  |  4  | Sakher     |
|  5  |  6  | Ahmad      |
| 11  |  50 | Hasan      |
| 110 | 113 | Omar       |
| 110 | 220 | Omar       |
| 113 | 220 | Omar       |
 ------------------------
```

Return the duplicates in one of the columns.
I prefer SQL Server query or standard ANSI SQL one.

Comment: Please provide a comment when down-vote!

Comment: "I need a query."  It's too close to just asking someone to do your work for you; will gladly revoke if the tone is changed.

Comment: What have you done so far? Plus Why does Omar still have 3 rows in the result? I think I don't understand exactly what you want. A little more detail

Comment: No, it is a very general issue, and not a homework to do!

Comment: You are right, the language is not good!

Comment: It's definitely a very valid problem, but you're still roughly saying "provide me with a query that fits my parameters" instead of "explain to me how I can do this".

Comment: +1 for the interesting question although you wrapped it in wordings as commented by @Brad Koch ...

Comment: @MSakherSawan . . . Can you explain why you want all pairs of duplicates?  In most applications, you just want the list of duplicates.

Comment: http://itzonesl.blogspot.com/2012/12/count-duplicate-records-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This query returns what you ask for. Comparing n1.id > n2.id is better than doing it like n1.id != n2.id because this way you would get every pair twice (the second time, reversed):

```
SELECT 
    n1.id as Col1, n2.id as Col2, n1.name
FROM 
    Names n1, Names n2
WHERE 
    n1.name = n2.name 
    AND n1.id > n2.id
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f27/5)

Comment: just a matter of `renaming n1.id as col1, n2.id as col2` ;) all good otherwise.

Comment: Good point. I also realized that it may be nicer to use < instead of >, but the result is still valid.

Comment: I editted your query to match exactly what OP needs as your answer is perfect and simple. Added the sqlfiddle demo, it's a great tool!

Comment: Awesome, especially sqlfiddle!

Answer (score 5):

```
Select count(*), name
from someTable
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

Will give you all the names that have duplicates, along with the number of duplicates, and might be more useful that the one you have requested. To achieve this, you could do the following:

```
Select a.id, b.id, a.name
from someTable a
 inner join someTable b
on a.id <> b.id and a.name = b.name
```